# Dependency injection in end-to-end tests

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I'm using Selenium along with NUnit for my end to end tests. I have some utility classes, loggers etc that I'm reusing throughout my tests. I would like simple injector to provide those instances to me.

Is there any way to integrate simple injector in NUnit? What I'm after is something like a wired up "TestLifestyle" container. Do I have any options besides passing around the container reference and disposing it manually in `[TearDown]`?

Comment: I've never used an IoC-Container within my tests when writing C#-applications. Is a mocking framework something you can work with here? I would recommend Moq, NSubstitute or FakeItEasy.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen I don't want to mock anything, I would like an IoC container to manage my utility classes within the tests.

Comment: Then I think you'll need the handle this yourself. AFAIK NUnit does not support this. You have to create your Container, register the dependencies, build your container and resolve the components you are interested in the test method.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen Right, what I'm after is an approach where I don't need to inject the container as a service locator

Comment: You should be able to just use your dependency injector of choice as you normally would. If you want to create a new configuration in a startup method, then you sure can easily, and that configuration will last the length of your test. You can even reference the registrations you've already created for your program

Comment: @MickelsonMichael Yes, but can the service locator pattern be avoided?

Comment: Can you make your question more concrete by adding an example of what you're doing?

Comment: Also note that, although a Container inside a unit test is typically not the best approach, using a Container inside your unit test is not a Service Locator. See: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/06/17/composition-root-location/

Comment: @filur as far as I know there is no way to integrate testing with any sort of dependency injection outside of creating a container. Perhaps another user has a solution but I'm afraid I don't see a way. As Steven said, try adding an example of what you'd like to achieve, or describe your goal a bit more

Comment: @filur Have you found a way to integrate dependency injection in nunit?